# Edge Detection and Angle-Extraction with Open CV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

Hey Guys i am currently trying to detect the Angle of a powder inside a Glass container.
The solution i got involves the use of Houghlines-Algorithm on an Image, preprocessed by gray scaling, thresholding, applying a gauss filter and at last using the sobel-operator to extract the edges. If i get my Hough-Lines back i use the fitline algorithm to fit a line inside all the detected points. Here is an Image of what i ended up with:

[image]

The Problem i have is that i am not really into Image-Processing and not sure whether this is a good approach or not to detect Angle with Houghlines and fitline, so is there a better approach of extracting these Informations so that i can improve my result ?

Comment: The result seems pretty well. Are you not satisfied with the accuracy? Why do you want to improve the algorithm if you already got a solution

Comment: Simplest approach: after smoothing + threshold: find largest contour, fitellipse, get angle of that ellipse.